# May I generate permutations of a long list for calculation without creating a huge list (in Python)?

Tags: python, permutation

I am currently having a project require me to find out specific permutations of a list of integers which fits certain conditions. I have tried itertools yet it generates a list which is too huge to my RAM which makes me can not even tried to put it in further calculations. I want to know if there is someway I can generate those permutations one by one and calculate them individually without having my computer loading a huge lists of data.

Comment: `itertools.permutations` returns an iterator, not a list.  If your code generates a list of permutations it's because you explicitly created one by either calling `list()` or wrapping it in a list comprehension (`[]`).  Just don't do that -- and if you're not sure how to change your code to make it work correctly, edit your question to include your current code.

Comment: To find "specific permutations of a list of integers which fits certain conditions" I have found backtracking algorithms to be much more efficient than generating and filtering through all permutations.  Hard to say, since you have not provided much information on the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`itertools.permutations`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html#itertools.permutations), just like most of the other functions related to collections in the built-in modules, returns a Python [iterator](https://docs.python.org/3/glossary.html#term-iterator).

In a nutshell, it means that each element of the resulting collection is returned one by one (or, in Python's terms, it is `yield`). The result is not automatically stored as a whole.

When you call `permutations`, you can either:

1. Instantiate an actual `list` or whatever collection with all the values at once.
   Example:

   ```
   seq = permutations(range(100), 4)
   list(seq)
   # beware, 94,109,400 elements, around 1.5GB of storage
   ```
2. Iterate on each value and decide to keep or discard each of them. You decide what is stored in memory.
   Example:

   ```
   seq = permutations(range(100), 4)
   predicate = lambda a, b, c, d: 50 < a == 25*d > b*2 < 4 < 3*c <= 15 >= 5*d
   list(p for p in seq if predicate(*p))
   # [(75,0,2,3), (75,0,4,3), (75,0,5,3), (75,1,2,3), (75,1,4,3), (75,1,5,3)]
   ```

Comment: Thanks a lot! A further question if it might be answered: how can I call each single element within each permutations instead of calling the permutations as a whole?

Comment: Hey I have solved it myself! appreciate for your answer!